# Can AntiForgeryToken be used in a Javascript Post?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

if so can show simple example, ex in jquery  ajax.post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie should be sent back with the request so if you serialize the input it should work.

```
$('form').submit( function() {
    $.post( $(this).action, $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
         ... do something with result
    }, 'json');
    return false; // prevent default submission
});
```

The key is to make sure that the data that you pass back to the server contains the hidden antiforgery token input.  In the case of the example above the antiforgery token must be included inside the form for it to work.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    ....
<% } %>
```

Comment: if i send ajax as such...  $.ajax(... can the token be included as a parameter?

Comment: Sure: use the data option and serialize the form inputs there:  data: $('#myform').serialize()

Comment: ie json token=_RequestVerificationToken?

Comment: You'd have to look up the value of the hidden input __RequestVerificationToken.   So it would be __RequestVerificationToken=$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').attr('value')